# Textview not showing inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I have the following XML file -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_product_title"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_row_item_description_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/products_row_item_product_description" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/very_light_grey"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_price_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="$999.90" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_heart_image_view"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/like_heart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_likes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_likes"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

creating the following layout -

[image]

But the issue is that I get the following result -

[image]

I have 2 question -

1) Why can't I see the price TextView?

2) I want to set a background color that will be visible between each row item. How can I do that considering my current layout? tried to give the Recyclerview a background color but nothing happens, it's like I have 0 spaces between each cell which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Just to confirm, the your `products_row_item_price_text_view` TextView is being set, right?

Comment: no, that was the cause for the problem. figured that out now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change width of text view to wrap content and replace tool:text to android:text

```
<TextView 
     android:id="@+id/products_row_item_price_text_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:text="$999.90" />
```

For  answer second :

Use view before end of parent linear layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation = "vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_product_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_product_title"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_description_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/products_row_item_product_description" />

       <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/very_light_grey"/>

      <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_price_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="$999.90" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_heart_image_view"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/like_heart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/products_row_item_likes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item_likes"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/very_light_grey"/>
   </LinearLayout>

     <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match"
        android:background="@color/very_light_grey"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great - thank you. What about the second question ?

Comment: now check my updated code to set borders at both side

Answer (score 2):

In your layout you use `tools:text="$999.90"` for the price `TextView`. It appears that you might not be setting the text manually. `tools:text` will only show up in the preview inside Android Studio.

Maybe something else like what @kam1234 is suggesting in his answer too

Comment: Great - thank you. What about the second question ?

Answer (score 1):

To show the lines between items, use

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: how can I make the borders much bigger? I want borders at all directions and thicker ones also